# ¿Por qué en español hay tan pocas palabras acabadas en "u"?

Tags: etimología, vocales

En el [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://dle.rae.es/) hay pocas palabras que terminan en "u": alrededor de 75, incluyendo expresiones latinas y palabras importadas.

¿Cómo es que hay tan pocas, en comparación con las acabadas en otras vocales?

Comment: Es por la evolución del idioma del latín. Lo que tal vez se habría resultado el *-u* se desarrolló en *-o*. Puede que por un periodo la pronunciación vacilaba un poco entre las dos letras: en portugués, a pesar de escribir *-o*, suele salir más como /u/, y en el asturiano, hay una diferencia entre *-u* y *-o*.

Comment: Efectivamente, aunque eso son desarrollos posteriores (demostrado en portugués por la propia grafía). En asturiano, creo, es cuestión de armonía vocálica.

Comment: @Paco en asturiano, *-u* es masculino y *-o* es neutro que se mantuvieron desde el latín, aunque innovando nuevos usos para el neutro. Con el portugués de verdad no sé mucho de su desarrollo histórico (sé que no escribieron al principio los dos tipos de vocales —abiertas y cerradas — a pesar de ya existir la distinción)

Comment: ¿El asturiano tiene neutro? (realmente no lo sé) :O

Comment: @Paco sí ho.  El neutro se emplea para cosas no contables (agua, gente, dinero, *l'agua ta frío* «el agua está fría») y también para infinitivos y cláusulas (  *el fútbol ye prestosu, pero xugalu nun ye tan prestoso* «el fútbol es divertido, pero jugarlo no es tan divertido»)

Answer (score 13):

Históricamente, la *-u* final de los étimos latinos tras la pérdida de *-m* (acusativo) se abría en *-o*, con lo que, teniendo en cuenta que la inmensa mayoría del vocabulario español procede del latín, es normal que no se conserve.

Ejemplo: *dominum* > *dominu* > *domino* (y ya luego, *domno*, *dueño*).

Por lo demás, las otras palabras del latín terminaban fundamentalmente en *-e* o en *-a* (tras pérdida de *-m*, etc.), con lo que de ahí tampoco podía salir ninguna *-u*.

Con todo esto quiero decir que las únicas palabras que actualmente terminan en *-u* son las que se han introducido de otras lenguas, más o menos recientemente, sin adaptar, o con una adaptación muy cruda.

Comment: +1; incluyendo, claro, que entre estas “otras lenguas” se encuentra también el latín mismo. El hecho de que la mayoridad de étimos en español son de origen latino no quiere decir que palabras latinas no se pueden introducir más tarde sin adapción.

Comment: Sí, pero «ímpetu» y «espíritu» son claros cultismos, mientras que «tribu» sea quizá una mera excepción caprichosa.

En cuanto a «tu» y «su», son resultados secundarios tras la apócope de los morfemas de género {-o, -a} (cf. italiano *tuo, tua, suo, sua*, etc.) ya en época del español histórico.

Comment: No sé, quizá esté ligado la «conservación como cultismos» debido a eso. Ya no te puedo decir.

No son apócopes del italiano, simplemente te digo que los compares. En italiano es *tuo, tua*, etc. porque en latín era *tuus, tua*, etc.

Comment: Si no me engaño, la *u* corta del latín prácticamente en todos los casos y todas las posiciones pasó a ser *o* (que diptongó en *ue* en los casos sabidos). La *ū* larga latina sí dio *u* en español pero el latín tardío casi no dejó vocales largas en sílabas finales.

Answer (score 2):

As Paco and Pablodf say, Latin or Late/Vulgar Latin words ending *-u* generally evolved into *-o* in Spanish. Whence disappeared most possibility of naturally inherited *-u* words in Spanish since no other terminal phone would conceivably evolve to /u/ in Spanish (unlike e.g. in Asturian).

That leaves the question though of where the few *-u* words that *do* exist came from. They come under a few different groups:

#### Pronouns

- *tu, su*

are apocopated forms of the *tuyo, suyo*. They lost their final vowels after the rule /-u/ → /-o/ was no longer productive.

#### Letters

The standardised names for letters are a relatively recent invention (16th century). Why *u* exists is clear. Qu and Gu seem to be pronounced thus by influence of the digraphs they occur in/as. Some others are loanwords from other languages.

- u, cu, qu, gu
- mu, tau (tao), wau

#### Acronyms, abbreviations

- preu, diu, ecu

#### Onomatopeia

- pu, bu, fu, hu, ju, jau, guau, miau, marramáu (marramao), [sucusumucu](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GZYDDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=etymology+sucusumucu), teruteru

#### Loanwords

This is by far the largest group coming from a number of different source languages:

- **Latin** a contrario sensu, in promptu (impromptu), stricto sensu, lato sensu, de visu
- **Catalan** bou
- **Italian** chau
- **French** art nouveau, chapeau
- **Arabic** alcuzcuzu
- **Basque** aurresku, chistu, sucu
- **English** mildéu, mildiu
- **Hindi** urdu
- **Bantu** ñu, hutu
- **Guarani** caráu
- **Aimara** pututu (pututo), sicu
- **Mapuche** llaulláu, pudu (pudú), temu, siu
- **Quechua** aillu, ayáu, ayayáu, ichu (icho), sirvinacu, pupu, quipu, uchu
- **American (misc)** caucáu, caucháu, cunchu, gonchu, pacumutu, quitu
- **Japanese** jiu-jitsu, tofu, sumu, haiku, sudoku
- **Chinese** kung-fu

#### ?

There are three exceptions I can find of Latin *-us* words which retained their *-u*. They don't (all) appear to be learned later borrowings, as spiritu/espiritus can be found consistently since the earliest available Spanish documents:

- tribu, espíritu, ímpetu

See here for more info: [Why tribu, espíritu, ímpetu, not *tribo, *espírito, *ímpeto?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28440/why-tribu-not-tribo)

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be looking at this wrong.

There are 5 vowels.

Two (a, o) are gender default.

One (e) is basically neuter.

The other two are no present outside of loan words and derived words esp. From Latin, Arabic, pt, and maybe it.